# GNOME Shell Notification with Inline Response in Python

Tags: python, notifications, gnome-shell

One of the features that I find most useful in GNOME Shell is the ability to respond to an IM directly from the notification. However, I was unable to find any documentation on how to create notifications like this. Can it be done in Python?

[image: This is what I am referring to]

Comment: Did you got any answer ? I'm really interested in that too :)